# Genesis 7: "The flood continued forty days on the earth." - is that same as forty days/nights?

Tags: genesis, grammar

Gen 7:12

> And rain fell upon the earth forty days and forty nights.

Gen 7:17

> The flood continued forty days on the earth. The waters increased and
> bore up the ark, and it rose high above the earth.

Are these two forty-day periods the same?

Comment: This question requires more details and clarity (no translation info given), and shows no effort at attempting to obtain an answer. We can't have thousands of questions in which the answer is "use a dictionary" - we are here for Biblical Hermeneutics and there must be a minimum bar where the questioner did some homework before asking a question of the community.

Comment: First verse should be Gen 7:12

Comment: The "original" Hebrew isnt any clearer: https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/7.htm

Comment: The text is ambiguous. The only way to solve it is to reconstruct the flood timeline.  The text contains clues linking the events of the flood to other biblical events. (e.g. the deaths of the patriarchs). Bear in mind that there were 2 floods. An Elohist flood and a Yahwist flood.

Comment: The short answer, is "YES" - same time period.

Comment: What's the alternative, that it rained consistently for 40 daylight periods, but then was completely dry for 40 night periods? Does the rain follow the daylight as the earth rotates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is quite simple.  Gen 7:12, & 17 say two things about the duration of the rain:

- Gen 7:12 - the rain was continuous (day and night) for 40 days, ir, it did not stop raining for 40 days
- Gen 7:17 - the flood "kept coming"/"continued", ie, the waters kept rising for 40 days.

That is, the actual rain and rising water was both continuous, without a break for 40 days.

Comment: @R.Emery - There are two things that militate against that idea (1) it requires an alteration to the text by adding "then" and "more", (2) the water kept rising in the same sentence, thus requiring further water.  We could also add a third, namely (3) the flood waters actually lasted (over all land) for more than 150 days, not just 40 days.